# Showing Previous data while adding new data to kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo grid it contains two records, after that i changed one row. It changing, changed data going to back-end and saving perfectly. While setting updated data to grid. It showing old value( i.e.,before i changed).

Example:

```
oldData = [{COL1:1,COL2:10,COL3:100}];
newData = [{COL1:10,COL2:10,COL3:100}];
kendoGrid.dataSource.data(newData);
```

Still its showing COL1 = 1 only

Comment: After Update Please Refresh your grid data, it's model is not updated so it's showing old data

Comment: @VinitPatel even thought i did data refresh also its show old data only

Comment: Have you check ajax call on refresh time? try to put debug on that time or if you are using batch editing then please ensure that your data updates in database....becasue if you are using batch editing then there is a sprate call for update data,so please ensure that there are data update in db..

Comment: With default behavior of Kendo Grid you do not need to set the updated data to grid. That will happen by default. Can you create an example of this in kendo dojo using their services? You can go http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline and click on "edit this example" and try to replicate the issue. Also you can try this way if you need this for some reason.

Comment: var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.at(0);//get record to update
data.set("COL1", "10");//set value. you can check all possible variations with this in kendo docs.